# Is gunzip module actually included in Nginx by default?

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-config

I have a new server with Debian 9.
I used `$ apt update & apt install nginx` to install Nginx.

After it was installed, I tried to check what modules are available: `$ nginx -V`

and I see, that **http_gunzip_module** was installed:

> nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
>
> built with OpenSSL 1.1.0k  28 May 2019
>
> TLS SNI support enabled
>
> configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic **--with-http_gunzip_module** --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-DhOtPd/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module

So, is **ngx_http_gunzip_module** included by default?

If yes, why [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) and [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#modules_not_default) we see, that http_gunzip_module is non-default module?

Comment: Built by default means built without the `--with-http_gunzip_module` option. Clearly, those that built the version that you have installed, did include the `--with-http_gunzip_module` option, and therefore the version you installed, does include that module.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I know in advance whether this option is enabled? Where is this data available?

Comment: I am not an expert with Debian or `apt`, but you may find the information you're looking for here: https://packages.debian.org/stable/httpd/nginx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is included in your build.
you have the `--with-http_gunzip_module` flag in your version check output.